# Query with min and max size in Django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have this model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height',)
    image_width=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    image_height=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    image_size=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,editable=False)
```

The view is like this:

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Image.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ImageSerializer
        filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
        filter_fields = ('image_name',)
        ordering_fields = ('id','image_name,)
```

I am able to save the images with all these attributes. I want to have a query like this to return all the images with height greater than 100 and less than 300:

```
GET /images/?minheight=100&maxheight=300
```

How to achieve this in Django?

I am getting 500 server error If I try to do fire the api with minheight empty 
`GET /images/?minheight=`

Comment: Can you share the (relevant parts of) your current view?

Comment: I've updated the view in the question itself

Answer (score 3):

In general, the query would look like:

```
qs = models.Image.objects.filter(image_height__gt=100, image_height__lt=300)
```

This uses the [gt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt) and [lt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#lt) field lookups. There are also variants for greater than or equal (`gte`) and less than or equal (`lte`).

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('image_name',)
    ordering_fields = ('id','image_name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Image.objects.all()
        minheight = self.request.query_params.get('minheight', '')
        maxheight = self.request.query_params.get('maxheight', '')

        if(minheight and maxheight):
            queryset = queryset.filter(image_height__gt=minheight,
                                       image_height__lt=maxheight)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Where I need to specify this query ? In the model or view

Comment: Just replace your queryset parameter if you want this to be the default. See [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) on how to manage query parameters if you want this to be customizable.

Comment: No, I want minheight and maxheight parameters to be optional. I am not understanding how to link these parameters to lt/gt lookups.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: /images/?minheight=
If I give minheight= empty value I am getting (500)server error

Comment: I've updated my example. Simply add a "default" value to the `get()` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You have to manually filter the queryset based on the `GET` parameters.

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('image_name',)
    ordering_fields = ('id','image_name,')

    def get_queryset(self):
        minheight = self.request.GET.get('minheight')
        maxheight = self.request.GET.get('maxheight')

        return self.queryset.filter(image_height__gte=minheight, image_height__lt=maxheight)
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but you need to validate that minheight and maxheight aren't None.